# Adding custom Typescript type declaration I get Cannot find module 'moduleName' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo, es6-modules

I have a react-native project on the expo and to make sure my objects are structured well I define custom modules. But when importing the modules in my components I get an error saying.

```
Cannot find module 'moduleName' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

The bellow is how I my module looks like

```
declare module "@event/test" {
  interface EventType {
    type: number;
  }
}
```

and this is how I import it in my component

```
import { EventType } from "@event/test";
```

and this is how I use `EventType`

```
  const eType: EventType = 2;
```

My code runs, but I get the error on the line that I import the module.
Can anyone help me?